# wp_logout_url($redirect); is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am writing a simple WP plugin that can log the user in and out. As far as login is concerned, it's working well; but I cannot logout through my plugin. Logout doesn't work after I login. I have tried a lot of suggested solutions but none of them worked.

My code is as follows:

```
function vrm_loginout(){

    if(is_user_logged_in()){

        echo '<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url($redirect); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>';

        //tried following as well
        //echo '<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() )>" title="Logout">Logout</a>'; title="Logout">Logout</a>';

    }else{

        wp_login_form();

    }//end of if


}//end of function

add_shortcode('vrm_loginform', 'vrm_loginout');
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong...You have a nested `<?php` tag within another `<?php` tag.

Comment: oh, thats cruel hahaha. which font is prefered?

Comment: @RobertP...as a user with a lot of rep, I'd expect you'd show a new user "the way" and edit the post for them (with an explanation), rather than downvote. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @DanishJameel, just the standard paragraph font. No need to make things headings ;-). I edited your question. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong...You have a nested `<?php` tag within another `<?php` tag. You should be using:

```
function vrm_loginout(){
    if(is_user_logged_in()){        
        echo '<a href="' . wp_logout_url($redirect) . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
    } else{
        wp_login_form();    
    }
}

add_shortcode('vrm_loginform', 'vrm_loginout');
```

Comment: Great! Please mark this answer as "correct" and upvote, if it's all working now. Thanks!

Comment: @DanishJameel You should upvote and/or accept the answer if this is what helped you. Because it will help other people with the same problem to see what the correct asnwer is.

Comment: i marked answer as correct but i cannot upvote it because i do not have 15 reputation. how can i accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url($redirect) .'" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
```